# Is there a formula for increasing the price whenever scarcity increases?

Tags: supply-and-demand, price

If this is not the right place to ask this, I'd appreciate it if you could direct me to the right one, if there is one.

1. I have a **fixed** set of items for sale
2. These items are unique, i.e. they are not sold anywhere else
3. *All unsold* items, at any time, have the *same* price
4. The **starting price**, when 0 items have yet to be sold, is **known**

***Every*** time an item is sold from the set (they will be sold one after another..), I want to increase the price of the remaining unsold items.

The price of the unsold items is not affected by anything else other than their own rarity.

Is there some common/"fair" financial rule on how I should increase the price of the remaining ones every time an item is sold, if I know the total number of items and their starting price ?

Since I haven't studied economics and I'm not familiar with mathematical formulas I would appreciate any answers similar to the below format.

Currently, the rather "naive" formula I could come up with was:

```
start_price = 0.04

// each time an item is sold:
fraction_sold = (total - remaining) / total
new_price_for_remaining = start_price + (fraction_sold * start_price)
```

But I find the increase rather "small" each time around.

I then tried:

```
start_price = 0.04
last_price = start_price

// each time an item is sold:
fraction_sold = (total - remaining) / total
last_price = last_price + (fraction_sold * last_price)
new_price_for_remaining = last_price
```

But the factor of increase grows exponentially to ridiculous amounts so I then tried:

```
start_price = 0.04
last_price = start_price

// each time an item is sold:
fraction_sold = (total - remaining) / total
last_price = start_price + (fraction_sold * last_price)
new_price_for_remaining = last_price
```

that shows a more "natural" price increase. But I'm still not sure if this is the best way. Lastly, I tried:

```
start_price = 0.04
last_price = start_price

// each time an item is sold:
fraction_sold = (total - remaining) / total
last_price = last_price + (fraction_sold * start_price)
new_price_for_remaining = last_price
```

where the price increase seems still somewhat "natural" but obviously more aggressive.

I understand there is no *absolute* law and that the factor of price-increase, each time around, is rather/also a subjective decision, but I'm wondering if there is at *least* some common/"fair" rule to go by/start with.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: this needs details and clarity, fair price according to what moral philosophy? There is no such thing as fair price from the perspective of economics as a science. Also what do you mean by financial rule in this context? If you want to find some sort of optimal price to maximize profit or some other objective be clear about that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess I agree with @1muflon1 :) - It boils downs to what I was suspecting in the OP, that what I'm asking is actually very subjective and there is no actual formula/rule on how I should increase the price each time scarcity increases. Having not studied economics I was naively hoping that there *could* be some sort of basic/initial formula that one could build upon (not a moral one but a purely mathematical/logical one) but I was wrong. Feel free to close if you feel this is of no use.

Comment: @Giskard my question was a rather "generic"/context-agnostic one. If I have N items at price S, is there some mathematical formula that indicates how the price of the remaining items should increase (if I want it to increase) every time an item is sold. I now realise that there is no such formula. :)

Comment: @SproutCoder 1. There are pricing formulas that don’t involve morals, but you can’t ask for **fair** price formula without some moral philosophy of what fairness is. 2. Morality aside, from purely scientific perspective in market prices are determined by supply and demand interactions that depend on scarcity as well that can be modeled mathematically but you are asking for some rule that only takes into account limited amount of the good so that is all off the table for you apparently. 3. If you are asking not about what we can generally observe in an economy but how to set prices regardless

Comment: Of that, then you have to at least specify so objective and objective function. Otherwise that’s like asking how should I choose my route? And when someone asks you where you wanna go, you ask no I just want to choose my route? Well that’s not enough details to help you at least you need to specify what objective is, what the target city or if you want to know some general decision rule then specify do you always want to find the shortest route (that will be just a straight line) or do you wanna take into account infrastructure (roads and bridges) or route that minimizes calories expended

Comment: For example do you want price that maximizes profit for your company? Do you want price that makes your company break even? Or price that maximizes loss of the company because you just feel like wasting resources? Do you want the price maximize your utility? Etc all of that can be answered objectively unless you want to talk about **fairness** which is domain of moral philosophy but you need to provide that information

Comment: *Should* one ask how one *should* set prices?

Comment: I am not a business. I have 1000 unique unsold NFTs currently on sale at 0.04ETH each. Every time one is sold, I want to increase the price of the remaining ones by some factor. I don't know what that factor should be and I guess there is no rule to that. I just have to decide more or less "randomly" I guess.